# Multiple UITextFields not displaying properly inside an UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller, xcode11

I need to display 4 UITextFields in an UIAlertController (Xcode 11.5). Did it as usual but the center UITextFields appear w/o border [view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg4eK.jpg)  and it doesn't look well (I am adding a screenshot). I tried to set the UITextField Borderstyle, frame, but I can't get it right.

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var dayOfWeekField = UITextField()
    var inicioTextField = UITextField()
    var terminoTextField = UITextField()
    var numeroDeCirugias = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Agregar Nuevo Bloque", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Agregar", style: .default) { (action) in

        let  nuevoBloque = Bloques(context: self.context)
        nuevoBloque.dia = dayOfWeekField.text!
        nuevoBloque.inicio = inicioTextField.text!
        nuevoBloque.termino = terminoTextField.text!
        nuevoBloque.cirugias = Int16(numeroDeCirugias.text!)!

        self.bloques.append(nuevoBloque)

        self.saveBloques()

    }

    alert.addAction(action)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .destructive, handler: nil))

    alert.addTextField { (field) in
        dayOfWeekField = field
        dayOfWeekField.placeholder = "dia de la semana"
        dayOfWeekField.autocapitalizationType = .none

    }
    alert.addTextField { (field2) in
        inicioTextField = field2
        inicioTextField.placeholder = "Inicio Bloque (HH:MM)"
        inicioTextField.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
    }
    alert.addTextField { (field3) in
        terminoTextField = field3
        terminoTextField.placeholder = "Término Bloque (HH:MM)"
        terminoTextField.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
    }
    alert.addTextField { (field4) in
        numeroDeCirugias = field4
        numeroDeCirugias.placeholder = "Número Cirugías"
        numeroDeCirugias.keyboardType = .numberPad
    }
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Four Textfields seem to be too many in my opinion... Wouldn't it be an option to use another `UIViewController`, maybe presented Modally? Or maybe implementing a custom `UIView` that will be presented in a modal kind of way rather than using the default `UIAlertController`?

Comment: You are right @mmika1000. But IMO it doesn't look that bad. I need the user to fill the 4 fields in order to create a "Surgical Day". The users will be doctors. No, worse...surgeons. So I'm trying too keep is as simple as its gets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. I suggest to not capture references to the `UITextfields`, maybe that might have caused the behavior. You can Access them by `UIAlertController.textFields` property. Usually all layouting is done by the `UIAlertController` basically fine, I never encountered bugs there.

Also. try to avoid force unwrapping with `!` by using `guard let`

```swift
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Agregar Nuevo Bloque", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Agregar", style: .default) { (_) in

        let nuevoBloque = Bloques(context: self.context)

        guard
            let dayOfWeek = alert.textFields?[0].text,
            let inicio = alert.textFields?[1].text,
            let temino = alert.textFields?[2].text,
            let numeroDeCirugiasString = alert.textFields?[3].text,
            let numeroDeCirugias = Int(numeroDeCirugiasString)
            else {
                // not all textfields were implemented or filled out properly
                return
        }
        nuevoBloque.dia = dayOfWeek
        nuevoBloque.inicio = inicio
        nuevoBloque.termino = termino
        nuevoBloque.cirugias = numeroDeCirugias

        self.bloques.append(nuevoBloque)
        self.saveBloques()

    }

    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    alert.addTextField { (field) in
        field.placeholder = "dia de la semana"
        field.autocapitalizationType = .none
    }
    alert.addTextField { (field2) in
        field2.placeholder = "Inicio Bloque (HH:MM)"
        field2.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
    }
    alert.addTextField { (field3) in
        field3.placeholder = "Término Bloque (HH:MM)"
        field3.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
    }
    alert.addTextField { (field4) in
        field4.placeholder = "Número Cirugías"
        field4.keyboardType = .numberPad
    }
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

EDIT: 
**Image of the Solution implemented by OP:**

[image: screenshot with your suggestion]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and for your help @mmika1000. I think yours is a safer code and swiftier, but it keeps showing the same layout behavior. Maybe UIAlertControllers shouldn't display 4 UITextFields and it's Apple's way to tell it. Maybe I'll try custom controllers or the Modal approach you commented above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FelipeAndai Wow okay that is really strange... Maybe you can try with two, then three to see if it'd be working generally? Anyway, you're welcome!